# Page go back in history when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a vertical unorder list of 5 radio buttons, with dynamic text generated every 2 minutes.

```
<ul id="answers_ul">
                                <li><input class="alternative-letter" id="r1" name="r1" type="radio"><div class="answers_letters">A</div><label class="res1" for="r1"></label><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg></li>
                                <li><input class="alternative-letter" id="r2" name="r1" type="radio"><div class="answers_letters">B</div><label class="res2" for="r2"></label><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg></li>
                                <li><input class="alternative-letter" id="r3" name="r1" type="radio"><div class="answers_letters">C</div><label class="res3" for="r3"></label><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg></li>
                                <li><input class="alternative-letter" id="r4" name="r1" type="radio"><div class="answers_letters">D</div><label class="res4" for="r5"></label><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg></li>
                                <li><input class="alternative-letter" id="r5" name="r1" type="radio"><div class="answers_letters">E</div><label class="res5" for="r5"></label><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg></li>
                            </ul>
```

The problem is the following. I add a button below the

```
<button class="clean_question"></button>
```

As the class is named, the function of the button is to clear the answers of the radio button (if checked).
But when I clicked it, the page load the previous page in history! That is really crazy.

I will paste the JS and CSS that is related to the clean_question button

CSS

```
button.clean_question{
 background-color: #292f33;
 border: 1px solid #55acee;
 width: 60px;
 height: auto;
 margin-top: 5px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-left: -34px;
 float: left;
 padding: 10px 12px;
 z-index: 100;
 position: absolute;
 transition: 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
}
button.clean_question:hover{
 transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
}
button.clean_question:before{
 content: url(../images/Examen_Botones_Clean.svg);
}
```

and the JS

```
    function resetRadio(el) {
    [].slice.call($('input[type="radio"][name="' + el.getAttribute('name') + '"]')).forEach(function(el) {
        var path = el.parentNode.querySelector('svg > path');
        if (path) {
            path.parentNode.removeChild(path);
        }
    });
}



jQuery('button.clean_question').on('click', function(){
    console.log('llegaste');

    selectsArr.forEach(function(obj,i) {
        [].forEach.call(obj.inputs,function(el){
            if (el.getAttribute('type') === 'radio')
                resetRadio(el);
        })
    });
```

Please try yo help me, I'm really stuck with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<button type="">` attribute defaults to `submit`.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html/forms.html#attr-button-type

So clicking it will submit the form by default. Form target is by default the same page, which results in reloading.
Use `<button type="button">` to avoid that.